# How to pack Android Gradle app to *.jar or *.aar file

Tags: java, android, gradle, ant, android-gradle-plugin

I created Android App with some gradle dependencies. Now I want to create from this project `*.jar` (without resources and add them separately) file or `*.aar` file.
I tried to create new library project (with build.xml), copied my `*.java` and res files and run `ant jar`, I'm fixing problem one by one. Is there any better solution to do this?

Comment: Ant knows nothing about AARs. Why are you using Ant, instead of Gradle, for this?

Comment: why ant? use gradle build. to change from app to library (aar file) just change from `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two modules.  The first module would be the `jar`.  This should be `POJO`s (Plain Old Java Object) and nothing Android.  The second module would be the `aar`.  This could depend on your first project but add on the Android specific code / resources.

Then your project (`MyApp`) structure would look like this

```
MyApp/
MyApp/build.gradle
MyApp/settings.gradle
MyApp/PoJoProject/
MyApp/PoJoProject/build.gradle
MyApp/AndroidProject/
MyApp/AndroidProject/build.gradle
```

Then your `settings.gradle` file would look something like this:

```
include ':PoJoProject', ':AndroidProject'
```

Now in the modules

In `MyApp/PoJoProject/build.gradle` you will want to apply the `java` plugin.  This module will build to the desired `jar` format that can be ran anywhere on the normal `JVM`.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

version '1.00'
group 'com.example.multimodule.gradle'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

In the `MyApp/AndroidProject/build.gradle` you want to apply the `android` plugin.  This module will build to the desired `aar` format and can only be used as an Android dependency.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

// version could be different from app version if needed
// `version` & `group` could also be in the top level build.gradle
version '1.00'
group 'com.example.multimodule.gradle'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.multiproject.gradle.android"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    // let the android `aar` project use code from the `jar` project
    compile project(':PoJoProject')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```